# Unity SetParent scaling in unexpected ways

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When using the SetParent function in Unity, the scale changes in an undocumented way.

I have tried using WorldPositionStays but this seems to absolutely murder the scale.

WithoutWorldPositionStays, the scale changes as is expected, as the new parent has the same LocalScale( 0.1, 0.5, 0.6 ) as the GlobalScale becomes.

I am confused as to why SetParent is not figuring out the correct scale to set when reparenting.

```
public class GhostInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject NewParent;
    public GameObject ParentThread;
    public GameObject PartToAdd;
    public GameObject AddThread;

    public GameObject ParentToTarget()
    {
        ParentThread.GetComponent<Thread>().Occupied = AddThread;
        AddThread.GetComponent<Thread>().Occupied = ParentThread;

        Debug.LogError($"GLOBAL: {PartToAdd.transform.lossyScale}, LOCAL: {PartToAdd.transform.localScale}");//OUTPUT: GLOBAL: (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), LOCAL: (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        PartToAdd.transform.SetParent(ParentThread.transform, true);
        Debug.LogError($"GLOBAL: {PartToAdd.transform.lossyScale}, LOCAL: {PartToAdd.transform.localScale}");//OUTPUT: GLOBAL: (3.8, 3.8, 1.0), LOCAL: (34.4, 7.3, 1.7)
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return null;
    }

}
```

```
public class GhostInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject NewParent;
    public GameObject ParentThread;
    public GameObject PartToAdd;
    public GameObject AddThread;

    public GameObject ParentToTarget()
    {
        ParentThread.GetComponent<Thread>().Occupied = AddThread;
        AddThread.GetComponent<Thread>().Occupied = ParentThread;

        Debug.LogError($"GLOBAL: {PartToAdd.transform.lossyScale}, LOCAL: {PartToAdd.transform.localScale}");//OUTPUT: GLOBAL: (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), LOCAL: (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        PartToAdd.transform.SetParent(ParentThread.transform, false);
        Debug.LogError($"GLOBAL: {PartToAdd.transform.lossyScale}, LOCAL: {PartToAdd.transform.localScale}");//OUTPUT: GLOBAL: (0.1, 0.5, 0.6), LOCAL: (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return null;
    }

}
```

When using SetParent(arg, true) I expect the object to keep its global scale at any cost. Is this an incorrect assumption? More than anything I just want to keep the GlobalScale of the parts as 1, 1, 1.

Comment: Errr, The output for those debugs is at the end of those lines.. Probably not a good spot for them, but not sure where else would be good...

Comment: Using `false` means that the local scale is retained as the parent changes. This we can see working correctly. When using `true` *an attempt is made* to preserve the global scale, but if the new parent object is rotated things may not work correctly. Is the new parent rotated?

Comment: Yes, the parent object is rotated. It seems scaling and rotation are entirely mutually exclusive features, so I just stopped scaling ANYTHING EVER in my entire project. Just seems like a simpler solution....

Comment: They aren't mutually exclusive, its that if the parent is rotated 45 degrees (and has a non-uniform scale) and the child isn't rotated the same amount, then the scale *cannot* be preserved (its literally impossible).

Answer (score 0):

Reversing a transformation is far from trivial. 
Unity applies Position, Scale and Rotation always in the same order in the *transform* component. But if you read the global scale and the global rotation, and you want to reverse them, you should apply reverse scale and reverse rotation *in the opposite order*.

This is why, if you use `Transform.SetParent(parent, true);` and the `parent` has both a rotation and a scale, Unity fails to reverse it and gives funny results. Btw, if `parent` has rotations that are multiple of 90 degrees, it usually gives correct results.

One workaround is to insert an empty `GameObject` between your `parent` and the `child` object. Let's call it `inBetween`. You then manually reverse the `parent` scale and apply reversed scale to `inBetween`, and reverse `parent` rotation and apply reversed rotation to `child`.
Mind you, this only works if `parent` has no parent objects itself (or at least, their transform is reset).